# Which elements of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ have multiplicative inverses ? And is $\mathbb{C}[x]$ a field?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}[x] = \{a_n x^n + \cdots + a_0 \mid \text{where each $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$}\}$.
Let $\mathbb{C}[x] = \{a_n x^n + \cdots + a_0 \mid \text{where each $a_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$}\}$.
The question is which elements of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ have multiplicative inverses ? And is $\mathbb{C}[x]$ a field ?

1). My guess is that the only elements of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ have multiplicative inverses are with $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. where $f(x)$ must also in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) \neq 0$.
Which means $f(x)$ must be a non-zero constant number in $\mathbb{R}$
in order to have a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.
Is this correct ?

2). My guess is that both $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are not fields.
Because if $f(x)$ is an non-constant and non-zero function in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ or in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.
Then, we cannot find any $(f(x))^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ or in $\mathbb{C}[x]$, such that $f(x) (f(x))^{-1} = 1$.
Becasue $(f(x))^{-1}$ will be rational functions not polynomial functions.
Is this correct ?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I assume that the point is that you justify your guesses a little more. In 1), you could consider what would happen with the degrees if a non-constant polynomial was a unit. In 2), it is true that a non-degenerate rational function is not a polynomial, but that's not a very algebraic argument. Since a proper answer to the previous part will have involved proving that polynomials of large degree are not units, it follows immediately that neither are fields.